# Problem publishing web site ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-4.0, webdeploy

I'm trying to publish a simple site with Visual Studio 2010.
I use Web Deploy. I'm getting the following error:

> Error 1   Web deployment task failed.(Object of type 'dbFullSql' and path 'Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=c:\documents and settings\tavi\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True' cannot be created.)
>
> Object of type 'dbFullSql' and path 'Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=c:\documents and settings\tavi\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True' cannot be created.
> Cannot connect to the database 'c:\documents and settings\tavi\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf'.
> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file c:\documents and settings\tavi\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.     0   0   WebApplication3

I deleted the `aspnetdb.mdf` file using [SQL Server Management Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio), and I'm still getting this error. What could be wrong?

Comment: Deleting the file usually works for the auto-attach issue. Are you sure you have deleted/DROPped the DB file, rather than detaching it from SQL?

Comment: i removed from sql server management studio (deleted it); it dissapeared from the Databases node; i also ran a DROP DATABASE aspnetdb query (after deletion) and i received the message:

Comment: Cannot drop the database 'aspnetdb', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: so, it's deleted, allright; but i still keep getting the error message when trying to publish the site

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue (but with SQL Server instead of aspnetdb.mdf) and this a solution that worked for me. I know that the question is old, but I am posting this for future references.

**Be aware that using this solution your database will be dropped before the new database is deployed. Thus is is a unsafe operation and does only fit for development.**

First off all I think the option of dropping the database should be available through a checkbox in the project settings, but instead we are forced to edit the project file manually. The entry to the is the article [How to: Deploy a Database With a Web Application Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28WEBAPPLICATIONPROJECTS.DEPLOYSQLWALKTHROUGH%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29&rd=true). In the section "Redeploying By Using Automatically Generated Scripts" we can read that setting `ScriptDropsFirst=True` in the `PreSource element` of the automatically generated script the target database will be dropped before the new database is deployed.

So, to do this: Open the `.csproj` file in notepad, find the section called `PreSource` (one for each configuration debug/release/...) and add the `ScriptDropsFirst="True"` element to it so that the entire xml tag is on the form
`<PreSource Path="Data Source=LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS%3bInitial Catalog=myDB%3bIntegrated Security=True" ScriptSchema="True" ScriptData="False" CopyAllFullTextCatalogs="False" ScriptDropsFirst="True" />`

Using these settings I am able to re-publish my databases as I wish.

---

Side note: This solution will hardly work in a production environment where you cannot drop your databases as soon as you need to update the solutions. Instead I would opt to use custom scripts to aid the update, as introduced in the section "Deploying Database Changes by Using Custom Scripts" in the same article.